# define several languages for code snippets

Tags: code-snippets

After consulting this link: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings in order to write some code, I concluded to this:

```
\lstset{ 
language=C, 
backgroundcolor=\color{highlight}, 
blah, blah, blah
}

\newcommand{\insertcode}[2]{\begin{itemize}\item[]\lstinputlisting[caption=#2,label=#1]{#1}\end{itemize}}
```

Finally, I didn't use the `newcommand`, instead I used `\lstinputlisting{my_file.c}` and it worked fine.

*(The file above is included int the `main.tex` file)*

Now I want to add a second language, would that be something like

```
\lstset{ 
language=python, 
backgroundcolor=\color{highlight}, 
blah, blah, blah
}
```

Should that be included in a different file? Should I create a new command in the same file? Is so, what would that be? In either case, could someone provide an example of the `newcommand` structure?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Are your settings per language fundamentally different other than the language specification itself? If not, why not just pass the language to the `\lstinputlisting` command?

Comment: You are right. Without fiddling with the code, just `\lstinputlisting[language=python]{my_file.py}` did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to have separate `\lstset` commands for each language if all of your basic formatting for code snippets is the same.

Use `\lstset` to set the basic parameters of the code formatting, and then in your `\lstinputlisting` command you can just pas the language as a parameter:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=C]{file.c}
\lstinputlisting[language=python]{file.py}
```

If you do want to have different styles for different languages, you can do so using the `\lstdefinestyle` command.  Here's an example of different styles used for LaTeX and Ruby:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{hello.rb}
class Hello
   def initialize(name)
      @name = name.capitalize
   end
   def sayHi
      puts "Hello #{@name}!"
   end
end

hello = Hello.new("world")
hello.sayHi
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{hello.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    breakautoindent=true,
    captionpos=t
}
\lstdefinestyle{TeX}{language=[LaTeX]TeX, frame=none,texcsstyle=*\color{blue}}
\lstdefinestyle{ruby}{language=Ruby, frame=leftline,keywordstyle=\color{red},numbers=left}
\begin{document}
\section{Sample LaTeX document}
\lstinputlisting[style=TeX]{hello.tex}

\section{Sample Ruby document}
\lstinputlisting[style=ruby]{hello.rb}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: is it actually possible to define multiple `lstset` without having them interfere with each other?

Comment: @naphaneal No not exactly, but you can define your own styles. I've added an example to show how to do that.